# SQL Server to Oracle migration - ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ora-12899

While migrating a SQL Server database to Oracle, I end up with an error

> ORA-12899: value too large for column

though the datatypes are the same.

This is happening with strings like 'enthält'. The data type `NVARCHAR(7)` should be able to hold the given string in SQL Server where as on Oracle `VARCHAR2(7)` not able to hold the value and throwing value too large error.

Is this something with the encoding style on Oracle? How can we resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What character set are you using, what is the DDL for your table, and what is the value of the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter? Could be that the column length in Oracle is being evaluated as bytes instead of characters.

Comment: The character set is UTF8, the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is Byte. Yes, the column length on oracle is set to bytes instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Oracle table with something like `varchar2(7 char)` this causes it to allocate in units of characters, not bytes.
This succeeds:

```
create table tbl(x varchar2(7 char));
insert into tbl values ('enthält');
```